# Why did Nintendo change their copyright title between Donkey Kong Set 1 and 2?

Tags: nintendo, arcade

Early American Donkey Kong arcade machines used  US Set 1 and the game title had "1981 Nintendo" as the copyright. Later US boards used Set 2 and Nintendo changed the copyright title to "1981 Nintendo of America". What was the main reason for changing the wording of the copyright title?

Comment: This looks more like a retro-law question than a retro-computing question.

Comment: I don't know if anyone outside of Nintendo can answer this question.

Comment: @LeoB.@JAL is this worth removing the question you think?...

Comment: Maybe leave it to let the community decide if it is on-topic.

Comment: I think it is marginally on-topic, but as @JAL said, to answer that question a very specific legal knowledge may be required, so a satisfactory answer is unlikely.

Comment: Of course it's on-topic, as it's related to  computer/game history. Still it might as well fit into an arcade related site.

Comment: The 1956 United Nations Berne Convention on Copyright defines what a claim to copyright is, and what it must contain.  This is really a question on how individual signatories to the convention ratify it within their own jurisdiction.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Quite simple, Nintendo of America was incorporated in 1982 in Redmond (!). Nintendo of America acted from there on as sole copyright holder for all sales within the US.

Before that US sales where in the name of the Nintendo (Japan). But copyrights are still today a national issue, where foreign companies may have a hard time to get their rights acknowledged. Even more so in the 80s.